# core data update not working after relaunch

Tags: ios, core-data

I have the following delegate callbacks which work correctly

```
// MARK: delegate callbacks
func updateViewControllerDidCancel(updateViewController: UpdateViewController) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

func updateViewControllerDidUpdate(updateViewController: UpdateViewController, parts: NSMutableSet) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    Helper.updateSession(updateViewController.session, parts: parts)
    self.fetchDB()
}

func createViewControllerDidCancel(createViewController: CreateViewController) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

func createViewControllerDidCreate(createViewController: CreateViewController, parts: NSMutableSet) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    Helper.createSessionForCurrentUserWithParts(parts, context: Helper.mainContext())
    self.fetchDB()
}
```

Create session is working. 
Update session works temperately, but after relaunch, the update is gone.

Here is how I setup `UpdateViewController`

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

    let session = sessions[indexPath.row]

    let updateVC = Helper.vcWithIdentifier(vcUpdate) as! UpdateViewController
    updateVC.delegate = self
    updateVC.session = session
    self.presentViewController(UINavigationController(rootViewController: updateVC), animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

And in the UpdateViewController, I call the delegate method like this

```
@IBAction func update(sender: AnyObject) {
    if selected.count > 0 {
        self.delegate?.updateViewControllerDidUpdate(self, parts: selected)
    } else {
        Helper.alert(self, message: "you have to pick at least one part")
    }
}
```

The 2 helper methods are:

```
static func updateSession(session: Session, parts: NSSet) -> Void {
    guard let context = session.managedObjectContext else {return}
    session.parts = parts
    do {
        try context.save()
    } catch let err as NSError {
        print(err)
    }
}
static func createSessionForCurrentUserWithParts(parts: NSSet, context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> Session? {
    guard let user = currentUser else { return nil }
    let session = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Session", inManagedObjectContext: context) as! Session
    session.user = user
    session.parts = parts
    session.datetime = NSDate()
    do {
        try context.save()
    } catch let err as NSError {
        print(err)
    }

    return session
}
```

And this is what gets print out for `context.save()`

```
2016-05-23 16:34:08.844 CrazyGym[5229:970972] CoreData: sql: SELECT t0.Z_ENT, t0.Z_PK, Z_FOK_USER FROM ZSESSION t0 WHERE  t0.ZUSER = ? 
2016-05-23 16:34:08.844 CrazyGym[5229:970972] CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0003s
2016-05-23 16:34:08.845 CrazyGym[5229:970972] CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0005s for 1 rows.
2016-05-23 16:34:08.845 CrazyGym[5229:970972] CoreData: annotation: to-many relationship fault "sessions" for objectID 0xd000000000040000 <x-coredata://4F69534D-B928-464B-8E9F-87329CB80C71/User/p1> fulfilled from database.  Got 1 rows
2016-05-23 16:34:08.845 CrazyGym[5229:970972] CoreData: sql: BEGIN EXCLUSIVE
2016-05-23 16:34:08.845 CrazyGym[5229:970972] CoreData: sql: UPDATE ZSESSION SET Z_OPT = ?  WHERE Z_PK = ? AND Z_OPT = ?
2016-05-23 16:34:08.845 CrazyGym[5229:970972] CoreData: sql: COMMIT
2016-05-23 16:34:08.846 CrazyGym[5229:970972] CoreData: sql: pragma page_count
2016-05-23 16:34:08.846 CrazyGym[5229:970972] CoreData: annotation: sql execution time: 0.0002s
2016-05-23 16:34:08.846 CrazyGym[5229:970972] CoreData: sql: pragma freelist_count
2016-05-23 16:34:08.846 CrazyGym[5229:970972] CoreData: annotation: sql execution time: 0.0001s
```

I only use the main context from AppDelegate

```
// MARK: core data
static func coreDataStack() -> CoreDataStack {
    return (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).coreDataStack
}

static func mainContext() -> NSManagedObjectContext {
    return coreDataStack().managedObjectContext
}
```

Comment: What Core Data stack are you using, Parent/Child? Have you tried instead of "guard let context = session.managedObjectContext else {return}" to use Helper.mainContext()? Even tho my advice is not to have only one context.

Comment: You have told us nothing about your contexts, please elaborate...

Comment: @ubiAle yes I have tried both and they are the same

Comment: @Wain I have editted the question

Comment: What else does the app do? Anything with files? Any validation rules in the model? Can't see anything obviously wrong in the code you've shown.

Comment: Can you tell us more about what you're trying to achieve? Does Session have a one-to-many relationship with "parts"? Do you actually insert/update the new parts somewhere?